# Is there any incarnation of Indra as per Rig Veda?

Tags: avatars, rig-veda, indra

From Puranas, we will come across incarnations of Vishnu, Shiva, etc.

I would like to know whether the Vedic God Indra took any incarnations, as per Rig Veda or commentaries on Rig Veda?

Comment: Arjuna and Vali might be partial incarnations of Indra

Comment: I am expecting from Rig Veda please

Comment: But we have rig vedic reference for incarnation vayu in Balaitha suktha as hunuman, bhima and madhva

Answer (score 1):

[An extract from this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SSammk5xUUEC&pg=PT112&lpg=PT112&dq=savya%20%2B%20incarnation%20of%20indra&source=bl&ots=BM-PgY7yRV&sig=ACfU3U26XP1uOcLDGljVWSMPeK2ihDhNwA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqmd-IwYLnAhWLwzgGHZ9ZBD4Q6AEwEnoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=savya%20%2B%20incarnation%20of%20indra&f=false) says that Rishi Savya was an incarnation of Indra.

> Savya is the rishi in Rig Veda and Sama Veda.  His Richas and mantras
>   are collected in Rig Veda 1:51 - 57 and in Sama Veda 373,376 and 377. 
>   He belongs to Angirasa Gotra.
>
> Acharya Sayana has explained that ***Savya was an incarnation of God of
>   Gods Indra***.  So he is called **Aindra**.

---

Even Bṛhaddevatā ([p.111](https://archive.org/stream/bhaddevat01univgoog#page/n130/mode/2up)) confirms this, supplementing the [following information.](https://archive.org/stream/bhaddevat01univgoog#page/n132/mode/2up) (p.112).

> Of the sage Angiras, who wished for a son like Indra, the bolt-bearer
>   himself became the son, having assumed the form of Savya.